# How can i Split data in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, split, strsplit

I want to split data on various factor like below

my data : "vs=1;am=0" fetched from one column from excel file

I want an output as below:

```
vs  am
1   0
```

I have tried:

```
s <- unlist(strsplit(Condition, split = ";"))
s <- strsplit(s, split = "=")
data<- data.frame(Condition = unlist(s))
```

but its getting all data in one column like below:

```
vs
1
am
0
```

Please help in splitting this into required structure(dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data<- data.frame(t(do.call("rbind",s)))
colnames(data)=data[1,]
data <- data[-1,]
```